# Bootstrap 4 inline navbar links

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to include an element in my navbar that says "Hello, user" which will redirect to the user's page when the username is clicked. I've been able to create a link that encompasses the entire "Hello, user" phrase, but I would only like the link to apply to the username.

Here's my code:

```
  <li class="nav-item">
    {# add user page #}
    <span class="navbar-text">Hello, <a class="nav-link" href="#">Trainer {{ user|title }}</a></span>
  </li>
```

When I try wrapping the code in span tags as above, it is displayed on the page as two lines. Is there a way to format this so that only the username is clickable while maintaining it all as one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "nav-link" class from your `<a>` tag and it will be one line. I'm guessing that class has a `display: block;` or something like that associated with it.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you